# How to upload Audio Recording and an Image at the same time to Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to allow a user to upload an image along with their audio recording. Per the Firebase documentation, I nested the database reference inside of the storage reference to upload them, but I'm unable to create and send URLs for both the image and audio. I could send them separately as two different database refs but that would cause issues when downloading them back to the application (without some type of identifier linking the image and audio).   If anyone knows how to send the two as one ref, your help is appreciated.

```
func uploadRecording () {
    if let audioRecording = recordedAudioURL {
        let audioIDString = NSUUID().uuidString
        let audioStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOT_REFERENCE).child("posts").child(audioIDString)

        audioStorageRef.putFile(from: audioRecording, metadata: nil, completion: {(_ , error: Error?) in
            if error != nil {
                print (error)
                return
            }
            audioStorageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url: URL?, error: Error?) in
                if let audioDownloadURL = url?.absoluteString {
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
                   sendDatatoDatabase(recordedAudioURL: audioDownloadURL)
                }
            })
        })
    }
    // upload selected image to Firebase
    func uploadImage () {
        if let lessonImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = lessonImg.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
            let photoIDString = NSUUID().uuidString
            let photoStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOT_REFERENCE).child("posts").child(photoIDString)

            photoStorageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {(_ , error: Error?) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                photoStorageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url: URL?, error: Error?) in
                    if let photoDownloadURL = url?.absoluteString {
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error)
                            return
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        )}
    }
```

For the newPostReference I receive an error : Use of unresolved identifier 'photoDownloadURL'

```
func sendDatatoDatabase (recordedAudioURL: String) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let postsReference = ref.child("posts")
        let newPostID = postsReference.childByAutoId().key
        let newPostReference = postsReference.child(newPostID!)
        newPostReference.setValue(["recordingURL": recordedAudioURL, "photoURL": photoDownloadURL, "lessonTitle": lessonTitleTextField.text!, "lessonTopic": lessonTopicTextField.text!, "lessonLocation": lessonlocationTextField.text!])
        self.lessonlocationTextField.text = " "
        self.lessonTopicTextField.text = " "
        self.lessonTitleTextField.text = " "
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    }
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear and I am not sure what a *messy download process* means. Can you clarify? And while you at it, it’s a good idea to include code and structures as text, not links and images. Please copy and paste a snippet of your code. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: The issue is still a bit unclear. There would be no issue with downloading the audio and image; 'linking' them is unnecessary. You could create a structure called *struct UserAudioAndImage* with two properties *var userAudio* and *var userImage* or they could populate a class or even (not recommend) keep them in two separate arrays. If you are downloading the *current* users audio and image you just have two class vars to store that data. Perhaps you could clarify where difficulty is with downloading two pieces of data and populating two vars from that data? Maybe a use case would help?